# Деплой Maven + Tomcat7

Tags: maven, java, tomcat

Вот такая ошибка при деплое проекта Maven в Tomcat7 (IDE Idea)

> [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ webapp-------------------------------------------------------------------------------[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ----------------------------------------------
> **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project webapp: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]** 
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException 
> Process finished with exit code 1

Отрывок из pom.xml

```
    <groupId>webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>tomcat</server>
                    <path>/webapp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Уже запарился, второй день мучаюсь. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, у вас не проходит деплой артефакта в репозиторий, а не в Tomcat.

Видимо вы выполняете `mvn deploy`, а нужно `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

Comment: Спасибо большое, BUILD SUCCESS!
НО! Во время выполнения вот такая неприятность случилась, может подскажете?
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/webapp
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
s.
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fwebapp (455 KB at 49
42.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:403, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

Comment: @artkon Это уже вопрос конфигурации. Документация вам в помощь: http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html